# How to make video textures transparent

Tags: texturing, transparency

I am making a minecraft animation, and I made the water animated. It worked, but when I set the viewport shading to rendered, the water was not transparent, even though I applied a transparent BSDF to it. How do I make it transparent? Thanks.

Comment: It's quite confusing what you're asking, do you want to render the animation as a video with alpha (transparency) channel? or do you want to use a video texture with an alpha channel in the Transparent BSDF?

Comment: I want to use a video texture with an alpha channel in the transparent BSDF.

Comment: Ok, add a image texture node with the video, create a mix shader with the first input as the material you want to use and the second input as the Transparent BSDF, then plug the alpha output of the image texture as the mix factor of the Mix Shader